# How to a precreated prefab convert to transparent object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, transparency

I installed a 3d model from internet. I add it to unity scene.But I try to convert transparent model. To do it, I create a material and change A channel(RGBA) in inspector panel.

By the way, I generate a transparent material. I drag it to model gameobject. Now, the model is transparent but it doesn't include rgb datas.

How to a model convert to transparent model with rgb datas?

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

1. Create material using `Assets->Create->Material`
2. Click material, on inspector set rendering mode to 'Transparency'
3. Change    A channel in RGBA
4. Click object on hierarchy, set material size 2(one of them is rgb, the other is transparency)
5. Drag yout    transparecy material and rgb image to the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a transparent material using an image, make sure that your rendering mode at the top of the material is set to 'Transparent,' and you load the image next to 'Albedo.'  If you want to change the transparency uniformly across the object, select 'Transparent,' but modify the A (alpha) channel as you described.

Comment: By this way, the object has only transparecy not rgb values.